# Flutter error: RenderFlex with multiple children has a null textDirection

Tags: flutter, dart, text-direction

I'm testing a widget that includes the following code (adapted from [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/76be55813b0710bf8e36edb532b0c24256484474/packages/flutter/test/widgets/editable_text_test.dart)):

```
await tester.pumpWidget(
  MediaQuery(
    data: const MediaQueryData(devicePixelRatio: 1.0),
    child: FocusScope(
      node: focusScopeNode,
      autofocus: true,
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          MongolEditableText(
            key: key1,
            controller: TextEditingController(),
            focusNode: focusNode,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
            cursorColor: cursorColor,
          ),
          MongolEditableText(
            key: key2,
            controller: TextEditingController(),
            focusNode: focusNode,
            style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 9),
            cursorColor: cursorColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

But when I do I get the following exception:

> Horizontal RenderFlex with multiple children has a null textDirection, so the layout order is
> undefined.

I tried adding a `textDirection` parameter to my custom widget that I'm testing but that didn't change anything.

*I found the answer [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67726#issuecomment-706148565), so I'm adding an answer below.*

Answer (score 5):

A flex widget like `Row` or `Column` needs to know the text direction of its children. There are three ways to do that.

#### 1. Use a WidgetsApp ancestor

MaterialApp and CupertinoApp use WidgetsApp internally. These all provide a default directionality.

```
MaterialApp(
  home: MyWidgetTree(
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
```

#### 2. Wrap with a Directionality widget

You can also wrap the row with a `Directionality` widget and give it a direction like this:

```
Directionality(
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
```

#### 3. Add a textDirection property

You can give the `Row` a direction using the `textDirection` property:

```
Row(
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  children: <Widget>[
```

#### Source

Thanks to [this comment](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/67726#issuecomment-706148565) for the help.