# flutter code to divide the vertical space of the screen in 3 different equal parts with different colors

Tags: flutter, dart

i want to divide my screen vertically in three equal parts with three diffrent color and i am getting only white screen in output.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const DivideVertically3EqualParts());
}

class DivideVertically3EqualParts extends StatefulWidget {
  const DivideVertically3EqualParts({super.key});

  @override
  State<DivideVertically3EqualParts> createState() =>
      _DivideVertically3EqualPartsState();
}

class _DivideVertically3EqualPartsState
    extends State<DivideVertically3EqualParts> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.orange,
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
        ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

here is code , i am getting white screen it should be orange , white and green.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing white screen probably because of the following error

> Horizontal RenderFlex with multiple children has a null textDirection,
> so the layout order is undefined.

You can check [Flutter error: RenderFlex with multiple children has a null textDirection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181322/flutter-error-renderflex-with-multiple-children-has-a-null-textdirection) to learn more about solutions of this error.

The easiest way to fix this is to wrap your widget with `MaterialApp`.

```
void main() async {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: DivideVertically3EqualParts(),
    ),
  );
}

class DivideVertically3EqualParts extends StatefulWidget {
  const DivideVertically3EqualParts({super.key});

  @override
  State<DivideVertically3EqualParts> createState() =>
      _DivideVertically3EqualPartsState();
}

class _DivideVertically3EqualPartsState
    extends State<DivideVertically3EqualParts> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.orange,
            )),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
            )),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.green,
            ))
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code need little bit changes.

```
double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
          width : width : width /3
          color: Colors.orange,
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
            width : width /3
          color: Colors.white,
        )),
        Expanded(
            child: Container(
            width : width /3
          color: Colors.green,
        ))
      ],
    );
```

Btw your code is perfect. And it's working for me as well,